# Change value in columns based off of another column in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

```
    df ex:
# A tibble: 20 x 2
   Autoswing `Duration(seconds)`
   <chr>                   <dbl>
 1 ✗                           4
 2 ✗                           5
 3 ✗                           7
 4 ✗                           6
 5 ✗                           8
 6 ✗                           9
 7 ✗                          11
 8 ✗                          16
 9 ✗                          16
10 ✗                           8
11 ✗                          12
12 ✗                          15
13 ✗                          10
14 ✗                         Inf
15 ✗                          14
16 ✗                         Inf
17 ✗                         Inf
18 ✗                         Inf
19 ✗                         Inf
20 ✗                         Inf
```

I would like to change all ✗ to ✓ in Autoswing if Duration(seconds) is inf. I was trying to use an if statement

Comment: Share your data with `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `base R` methods i.e check for infinite values with `is.infinite` to create a logical vector and do the assignment

```
df$Autoswing[is.infinite(df$`Duration(seconds)`)] <- "✓"
```

-output

```
> df
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   Autoswing `Duration(seconds)`
   <chr>                   <dbl>
 1 ✗                           4
 2 ✗                           5
 3 ✗                           7
 4 ✗                           6
 5 ✗                           8
 6 ✗                           9
 7 ✗                          11
 8 ✗                          16
 9 ✗                          16
10 ✗                           8
11 ✗                          12
12 ✗                          15
13 ✗                          10
14 ✓                         Inf
15 ✗                          14
16 ✓                         Inf
17 ✓                         Inf
18 ✓                         Inf
19 ✓                         Inf
20 ✓                         Inf
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.infinite(`Duration(seconds)`), Autoswing := "✓"]
```

---

Or with `dplyr` using `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(Autoswing = replace(Autoswing, is.infinite(`Duration(seconds)`), "✓"))
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   Autoswing `Duration(seconds)`
   <chr>                   <dbl>
 1 ✗                           4
 2 ✗                           5
 3 ✗                           7
 4 ✗                           6
 5 ✗                           8
 6 ✗                           9
 7 ✗                          11
 8 ✗                          16
 9 ✗                          16
10 ✗                           8
11 ✗                          12
12 ✗                          15
13 ✗                          10
14 ✓                         Inf
15 ✗                          14
16 ✓                         Inf
17 ✓                         Inf
18 ✓                         Inf
19 ✓                         Inf
20 ✓                         Inf
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Autoswing = c("✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", 
"✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", 
"✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗", "✗"), `Duration(seconds)` = c(4, 
5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 11, 16, 16, 8, 12, 15, 10, Inf, 14, Inf, Inf, 
Inf, Inf, Inf)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option is to use `transform`:

```
df <- transform(df, Autoswing = ifelse(`Duration(seconds)` == "Inf", "✓", Autoswing))
```

Output:

```
   Autoswing Duration.seconds.
1          ✗                 4
2          ✗                 5
3          ✗                 7
4          ✗                 6
5          ✗                 8
6          ✗                 9
7          ✗                11
8          ✗                16
9          ✗                16
10         ✗                 8
11         ✗                12
12         ✗                15
13         ✗                10
14         ✓               Inf
15         ✗                14
16         ✓               Inf
17         ✓               Inf
18         ✓               Inf
19         ✓               Inf
20         ✓               Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tibble(
    Autoswing = c("✗","✗"),
    `Duration(seconds)` = c(2,Inf)
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(Autoswing = if_else(`Duration(seconds)` == Inf,"✓",Autoswing)) %>% 
  glimpse()

Rows: 2
Columns: 2
$ Autoswing           <chr> "✗", "✓"
$ `Duration(seconds)` <dbl> 2, Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  Autoswing = c("✗", "✗"),
  Duration = c(5, Inf)
)
df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   Autoswing Duration
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 ✗                5
#> 2 ✗              Inf
df %>%
  mutate(
    Autoswing = Autoswing %>% map2_chr(Duration, ~ ifelse(is.infinite(.y), "✓", .x))
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   Autoswing Duration
#>   <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 ✗                5
#> 2 ✓              Inf
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>